# Handling key for image decryption in AWT application

Tags: java, image-processing, encryption, blowfish

I have the following code for decrypting an encrypted imaged. My problem is if i do the encryption of the image and the decrpytion of the image at one go, it does it without a problem. But if i encrypt the image and wait for some time and try to decrypt the image, it throws me this exception.

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Below is my code for decrpting

```
public void decrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) {  
        File encryptedFile = new File(srcPath);  
        File decryptedFile = new File(destPath);  
        InputStream inStream = null;  
        OutputStream outStream = null;  
        try {  
            inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);  
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);  
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
            int len;  
            while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
                  outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));  
                  outStream.flush();  
                  }  
                  outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());  //I guess this line throws the error 
                  inStream.close();  
                  outStream.close();  
              } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {  
                   System.out.println(ex);  
             } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {  
               System.out.println(ex);  
             } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {  
                    System.out.println(ex);  
             } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {  
                 System.out.println(ex);  
                 } catch (IOException ex) {  
                  System.out.println(ex);  
        }  
}
```

Encryption code

```
 public FunctionClass() {  
        try {  
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");  
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();  
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");  
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    }  
}

 public void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) {  
    File rawFile = new File(srcPath);  
    File encryptedFile = new File(destPath);  
    InputStream inStream = null;  
    OutputStream outStream = null;  
    try {  
        /** 
         * Initialize the cipher for encryption 
         */  
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);  
        /** 
         * Initialize input and output streams 
         */  
        inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile);  
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        int len;  
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));  
            outStream.flush();  
        }  
        outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());  
        inStream.close();  
        outStream.close();  
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    } catch (IOException ex) {  
        System.out.println(ex);  
    }  
}
```

Button code

```
 private void btnEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int o=jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(o==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File f=jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        String path=f.getAbsolutePath();

        FunctionClass Encrypt= new FunctionClass();
               String directoryPath = "C:/Users/Desktop/";
                   String encryptedFile = "encryptedFile.jpg";  
        Encrypt.encrypt(path, directoryPath+encryptedFile);
    }
}

  private void btnDecryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
                          int o=jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(o==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File f=jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        String path=f.getAbsolutePath();

        FunctionClass Encrypt= new FunctionClass();
               String directoryPath = "C:/Users/Desktop/";
      String decryptedFile = "decryptedFile.jpg"; 
        Encrypt.decrypt(path, directoryPath+decryptedFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the title to be a more descriptive. Can you check that this is still what you were essentially asking?

Comment: Please delete those obsolete comments. [This comment will self-destruct in 30, 29, 28...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you generate the key in the `FunctionClass` constructor, but you construct the object in both `btnEncryptActionPerformed` and `btnDecryptActionPerformed`. Because you chose to generate the key in the constructor, you need to have only one instance of `FunctionClass` in your class.

You can make `FunctionClass Encrypt= new FunctionClass();` a static variable of the class.

There is a problem though. You will probably need to decrypt something in another session than when you encrypted the file. With the above advice, you will not be able to decrypt the file after you close and reopen your application. You need some kind of persistance layer where you save the key into. This layer would probably need to be encrypted with a master key.